# Sample connection for HIVE and Python

Tags: python-2.7, hive, hiveql

I am trying to connect python with hive data base .
Both are on different server.
hive resides on host xx.xxx.xxx.x and python is on my local system.

i am trying to use the below code , however its not working

import pyhive
from pyhive import hive

conn = hive.connect(host = 'xx.xxx.xx.xx', port = 8888, auth = 'KERBEROS', kerberos_service_name='adsuedscaihen01.aipcore.local', username ='user1', database = 'database1'
)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT * from table1')
result = cur.fetchall()
print(result)

while i run the above code , i am facing the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 64, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 162, in **init**
    self._transport.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line 79, in open
    message=("Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()))
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)

Comment: Kerberos demands **canonical DNS names** for servers _(i.e. converting name to IP then IP to name should return the same exact host name)_ => no IP address, no DNS alias, no load balancing. The goal is to block IP spoofing attacks.

Comment: Recommended reading: _"Hadoop and kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ by Steve Loughran [HortonWorks], and especially https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html